# Find sufficient and necessary conditions for which the area of $A$ is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $A$ the triangle formed by the vertices $(x₁,y₁),(x₂,y₂),(x₃,y₃).$

Find sufficient and necessary conditions for which the area of $A$ is zero.

If the vertices $(x₁,y₁),(x₂,y₂),(x₃,y₃)$ are equal, then the triangle will shrink to a single point and hence its area is zero, but this is not the general case.

Comment: That's a very simple case in which the area is zero. Can't you think of a less trivial case? Then the rest should be fairly obvious, or something you can easily get help on.

Comment: @Henrik: How we can explain this geometrically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix one of the vertices and form the vectors describing two sides: for example $u (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$ and $v = (x_3-x_1, y_3-y_1)$. The triangle will have area zero if and only if $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, i.e. if and only if
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}
x_2-x_1 & y_2-y_1 \\
x_3-x_1 & y_3-y_1
\end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$

Comment: @ mrf: How we can explain this geometrically

Comment: All three points will be collinear.